# pytest 3.5.0 broke celery tests

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

After pytest update from 3.4.2 to 3.5.0 my celery tests was crashed with error

```
Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark,
or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

I have tried to add `@pytest.mark.django_db` to my test, but nothing cahnges.

Code:

conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_session_app(request):
    """Session Fixture: Return app for session fixtures."""
    yield django_celery_app

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_session_worker(request,
                      celery_session_app,  # noqa: pylint=redefined-outer-name
                      celery_worker_pool,
                      celery_worker_parameters):
    """Session Fixture: Start worker that lives throughout test suite."""
    with worker.start_worker(celery_session_app,
                         pool=celery_worker_pool,
                         **celery_worker_parameters) as worker_context:
        yield worker_context
```

Test:

```
def test_create_task(celery_session_worker):
    x = debug_task.delay()
    assert x.status in ['PENDING', 'SUCCESS']
    assert x.get(timeout=20) == "Request: '_project_.celery.debug_task'"
```

Comment: What happens if you changes the scope of fixture `celery_session_worker` to `function` and add the `db` arg to the fixture args: `def celery_session_worker(db, request, ...)`?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: I updated pytest version if I remember it right